# Update data using IF in mysql and define 'dont do anything' when if false

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update

Im trying to use IF query in update some entire row in my mysql table. As known IF query have 3 parameters. Part 1 of what you looking for, part 2 if its found / true and part 3 if its not found / false. 
I just want it to be update when its true and doing nothing if false. How to define 'dont do anything' so the false part wont be update into anything else? Sorry for my bad english. And thanks for your help.

Comment: should us what you have tried so far.

Comment: So far i try it by update trough the select statement. But i found its useless. I've found what i need with this code :
`UPDATE login SET passw= IF(lvl = '1', 'abc123', passw)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign the same value of column in FALSE part to do nothing.

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableA SET COL1 = IF(a=b, c, COL1)
```

Comment: Thanks mister. I forget about the reassignment with same value will make "nothing to do" effect :)

Comment: But perhaps the code will be like this : `UPDATE tableA SET col1 = IF(a=b, c, col1)` you didnt write the IF in the assignment and i couldnt edit it because its less than 6 character :)

Comment: This is inefficient because it impacts all rows and only changes some of them. Your database is not going to like you if this only updates a small percentage of the actual rows since it has to evaluate every single one of them.

Comment: @NinaSuhari You're most welcome. I forgot to write `IF`. I had updated my answer

Comment: @tadman OP wants to update only those rows where the condition was satisfied. User can do that adding that condition in WHERE clause but if the OP wants to update more than one columns and update one column based on condition and other columns without condition.

Comment: That's a better interpretation than what I got. In that case this makes sense, though the example is too contrived.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing an update with a condition with a conditional update. For example the following is an update with a condition:

```
UPDATE x SET y=IF(a=b, c, d)
```

This is a conditional update:

```
UPDATE x SET y=c WHERE a=b
```

The first version is applied to all rows, the second to all *matching* rows.

Use a `WHERE` clause to limit what rows your `UPDATE` is applied to.

Comment: In the first condition using IF, i dont want it to be update to d if found the condition false :)
I'll take the answer below by @saharsh . thanks for your comment :)

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. The second one can be adjusted to update `y` to whatever you want with whatever conditions. It's far more efficient to update a sub-set of the rows than all of them with a non-assignment.

Comment: I want it to be use not only for "not taking an update its false", but also i can switch the false parameter to another thing for future. So i'll take the one with IF. Thanks for your comment.